# Formatar células do excel através do code behind

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma rotina que gera uma planilha em excel, vinda de um banco de dados Oracle. O que passa é que na BD tenho valores assim:
`3456.90` ou `1900.00`
Quando esses valores chegam na planilha, ela mostra assim:
`3456,90` ou `1900`

ou seja, quando o valor tem os dois últimos dígitos após a o ponto, com valor 00, na planilha mostra um número inteiro. Como isso é um relatório, a planilha precisa já ter os valores formatados e não o usuário formatar manualmente. Há como fazer? É exportado em formato `.csv`. Há como fazer isso?
No meu Page Load está assim:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var conexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TS"].ConnectionString;
            var connectionOracle = new OracleConnection(conexao);
            connectionOracle.Open();
            var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql(), connectionOracle);
            OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ItemMatMed itemMatMed = new ItemMatMed();

            try
            {
                Response.Write("Data de Inclusão;Tipo de Tabela;Tabela;Codigo;TUSS;Descrição;Fabricante;Referência do Fabricante;Registro ANVISA;Classificação SIMPRO;Grupo Mat/Med;Grupo Estatístico;Autorização Prévia;Última Vigência;Valor;Tabela Própria;");
                Response.Write("\r");

                while (odr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write(odr[0].ToString() + ";" + odr[1].ToString() + ";" + odr[2].ToString() + ";" + odr[3].ToString() + ";" + odr[4].ToString() + ";" +
                                   odr[5].ToString() + ";" + odr[6].ToString() + ";" + odr[7].ToString() + ";" + odr[8].ToString() + ";" + odr[9].ToString() + ";" +
                                   odr[10].ToString() + ";" + odr[11].ToString() + ";" + odr[12].ToString() + ";" + odr[13].ToString() + ";" + odr[14].ToString() + ";");  

                    Response.Write("\r");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                connectionOracle.Close();
                connectionOracle.Dispose();
            }

            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=relacao_materiais.csv");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Realmente o que eu quero não dá certo. O String.Format que eu passei está correto. Acontece que se a célula não estiver formatada, o excel sempre vai mostrar um valor absoluto, caso após esse valor seja, vírgula seguida de zeros. O usuário terá que formatar a célula por sua conta e risco.